# using compareTo method when overriding compareTo?

Tags: java, interface, compareto

when implements Comparable interface and override compareTo method,

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Name o) {
    int val = this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    if (val != 0) {
        return val;
    }        
    if (count != o.count) {
        return count - o.count;
    }
}
```

The third line, I realized that I can use compareTo when I override it, and it automatically compares things follows the natural order. But isn't compareTo an abstract method in the comparable interface. Without defining it, it still does compare? Also, why I do not need to use super keyword to distinguish this compareTo.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the method `compareTo` in the `class Name extends Comparable<Name>`. This class has a member called `name`.If you were calling `Name.compareTo` in the third line, you would get a crash from infinity recursion, nor can you call `Comparable.compareTo`, which is abstract indeed.

You are calling `X.compareTo`, where X is the type you declared the member variable `name` with.

In other words, this will only work if `name` is not `instanceof Name`.

By the way, you will need to add an else branch with a return statement to your last if block, or this snippet won't compile.