# Why use compareTo() from Comparable Interface when overriding the compareTo() method?

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I have been googling around and the closest response (not answer) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680973/using-compareto-method-when-overriding-compareto), but I am confused of the response.  I am trying to sort some dog names using Collection.sort(), so I need to learn to use Comparable interface.  My questions:

1) why do I need to use the compareTo() that came from the interface when I "override" the compareTo()?
2) If the compareTo() from Comparable interface is a default method, why doesn't it has a "default" keyword in front of the method?  [Java SE 8 Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Here is the partial code:

```
Collections.sort(list);   
for(Dog a: list)   // printing the sorted list of names
     System.out.print(a.getDogName() + ", ");
```

Here is the class implement the Comparable interface:

```
class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog> {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   Dog() {}

   Dog(String n, int a) {
      name = n;  age = a;
   }

   public String getDogName() {
      return name;
   }

   public int getDogAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public int compareTo(Dog d) {
      return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);  //###.....my question
   }

   // Override Comparator Interface's compare() to sort "ages"
   public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1) {
      return d.age - d1.age;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'use', and how can you override a method without having a method to override? Where does it say it's a `default` method? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP , here is an example out of a bunch of articles online using the word, "override," when they talk about creating their own compareTo method of Comparable interface.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: @EJP, Additionally, an interface can have a default method that is already implemented in an interface since Java 8.  Since many articles I found says "override" compareTo() when they implement Comparable interface and they call compareTo() a default method, I asked if compareTo() is a default method in my post.

Comment: You didn't ask that in your question. You asked *why* it doesn't have `default` *if* it is a default method. The question doesn't make sense. It is only a default method *if* it has `default` in its declaration. You don't appear to understand your own question.

Comment: @EJP , I see you don't understand my question.  lol

Comment: That is correct. I don't. It's up to you to clarify it. You haven't answered any of my three questions. And you didn't ask what you now claim you asked, as I've already stated. 'Can have' isn't the same as 'does have', and 'if X' isn't the same as 'is X?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to think about.

A `Dog` is `Comparable` to other `Dog`s. It is not itself something that compares two *other* `Dog`s.

So, implementing `Comparable` is "more correct".

And you are conflicting two methods.

> `static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`
>
> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>   natural ordering of its elements.

So, `Collections.sort(dogs);` will sort your list.

> `static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`
>
> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the
>   specified comparator.

This is how you use that method.

```
Collections.sort(dogs, new Comparator<Dog>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Dog d1, Dog d2) {
        return d1.compareTo(d2); // Call the Comparable method
    }
)};
```

You can, of course, implement that inner method to order by age

```
return Integer.compare(d1.getAge(), d2.getAge());
```

Comment: Thanks, @cricket_007.  But where is the original compareTo() implemented from the line, return d1.compareTo(d2);  ?

Comment: `Dog implements Comparable<Dog>`

Comment: Yes. What about it?

Comment: Collections.sort(dogs, new Comparator<Dog>() {......}); => this line from your answer implements a Comparator interface.  But a Comparator interface doesn't have compareTo() to be overridden. Why did you call the Comparable method? Thanks for your help.  :)

Comment: Okay, I had a typo. Sorry about that

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for getting back to me promptly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> why I need to use the compareTo() that came from the interface when I
>   "override" the compareTo()?

So that you can customize the logic based on your data structure used , so in your case you are using Dog object which cannot be defaultly sorted by the Collection API as they work on primitive data type sorting only not on custom objects.

So it asks for overridding the compareTo() and provide the custom logic nowas your keyword for sorting is String "name" you may use its compareTo() method for sorting.

> 2) If the compareTo() from Comparable interface is a default method,
>   why doesn't it has a "default" keyword in front of the method?

Because in case of primitive data types sorting `Collections.sort()` internally uses `Arrays.sort()` and that there is no default implementation of compareTo() method in the Comparable interface

Comment: Based on the 1st part of your explanation, it seems to me the original compareTo() that comes with Comparable interface is already implemented to sort String objects, right?

Comment: @LEDFantom Well, [`String implements Comparable<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)